# polymer paper-icon-button specify width of icon

Tags: html, css, polymer

Using

```
<paper-icon-button icon='image:photo' fill="true"></paper-icon-button>
```

I have the correct icon, but unfortunately, it's small (around 24px).

I tried to specify the width :

```
paper-icon-button {
    min-width: 50px;
}
```

But it's not working.
Is it possible to specify the width for the icon ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `core-icon`s themselves are resizeable, this is one of the reasons we use SVG (by default;  another reason being the ability to colorize).

But `*-icon-button` doesn't provide a conduit for controlling this size.

I created some issue tickets:

https://github.com/Polymer/core-icon-button/issues/3

https://github.com/Polymer/paper-button/issues/9

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried but finally switch to a more 'basic' solution (a simple image). Even if I don't have the 'glossy' touch effect on my image, it's works !

Comment: The correct answer can be found below and should be accepted! Polymer provides mixin to change the button style.

Answer (score 11):

In 1.1, the correct way to do this is:

```css
.my-button {
  --paper-icon-button: {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Since Polymer 1.x CSS variables provide a convenient way to achieve the desired effect. In case of `paper-icon-button`, which incorporates `iron-icon` it is possible to set `iron-icon` specific [CSS variables](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-icon):

```
.my-button {
--iron-icon-height: 24px;
--iron-icon-width: 24px;
}
...
<paper-icon-button icon="menu" class="my-button"/>
```

Comment: Were you actually able to get this working? Setting these properties doesn't work for me. For example, I set them both to 100px, but the icon size still ends up being the default of 24px

Comment: @nickjm Absolutely! Otherwise why would I post it (: If you're trying this to work in the "main" html file then please make sure style is annotated with custom-style. That is "<style is="custom-style">...".

Comment: Yep that worked! Is it possible to add the 'is="custom-style"' annotation to a css file (e.g. main.css)?

Comment: @nickjm As a general rule it is recommend to express everything as a custom element (web component) as much as possible where there is no need to use 'is="custom-style"'. Importing CSS files is still experimental in Polymer 1.0.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work in 1.1.  The correct way to do it now is to use the `--paper-icon-button` mixin and set `width` and `height` there (see my answer below).

Answer (score 1):

you can try this workaround:

```
paper-icon-button::shadow core-icon{ 
    -moz-transform: scale(2); 
    -webkit-transform: scale(2); 
    transform: scale(2); /* 48px */

    fill: rgb(255,255,255);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
core-icon-button::shadow core-icon {
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
}
or
paper-icon-button::shadow core-icon {
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
}
```

Works.

Answer (score 1):

I used the css attribute 'zoom' to enlarge. Works for me in Chrome. Haven't tested on Safari or Firefox yet.

Answer (score 0):

icon size is specified in the core-iconset element:
http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-iconset

Comment: We cannot re-use the default icon ? Because iconset is used to build icon from a specific image file. In my case, I want to use default icon (image:photo).

Answer (score 0):

paper-button, paper-icon-button attribute `min-width` only accepts EMs as a value.

e.g. `min-width: 1em;`

1em = 16px

for px to em conversion -> [click here](http://pxtoem.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally change the icon size by setting the following css properties:

```
paper-icon-button iron-icon.iron-icon-0 {
    width: /*yoursizehere*/
    height: /*yoursizehere*/
}
```

I found this after digging around in the development console to see what properties actually change something. This may not be the most correct solution, but other answers like 01es's didn't work:

```
.my-button {
    --iron-icon-height: 48px;
    --iron-icon-width: 48px;
}
```

Those properties either didn't change anything or were overridden.